# In the cocountable topology are singletons open?

Tags: general-topology

So we can define the cocountable topology as $\mathcal{T}_{c.c} = \{U \subseteq X| U = \emptyset, X-U \mbox{is countable}\}$. So suppose that we have $\{x\} \in \mathcal{T}_{c.c}$. Then by definition of the cocountable topology we have that $X- \{x\}$ is countable. I found out that the open sets in this topology are the ones that empty set, and the subsets whose complements are finite or countable. What can we conclude about singletons in this space. Are they open, or closed?

Comment: Your definition is slightly wrong but of course it depends on if the space is countable or not

Comment: Well for example if $X = \mathbb{R}$ then this definition holds right?

Comment: no, because it should be U subset of X not X subset of U.

Comment: well shoot you're right, I messed up that notation !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X $ is countable yes, the topology is discrete.   But if not then $X-\{x\} $ is uncountable,  so the singletons  $\{x\} $ are not open. They are closed,  however,  because their complements are open.  $X\setminus(X\setminus\{x\})=\{x\} $ is finite.  So the topology is always  $T_1$.